# Apple Developer Distribution Certificate

Tags: iphone, ipad, certificate, app-store

Quick question. Our apple developer distribution certificate expires at the end of this month. When it expires it does not effect any apps that are currently up on the app store (that the expiring dist. certificate was used with), correct?

It only means for future distribution a new certificate will need to be created to submit apps to apple, correct?

Im pretty sure i know the answer, just one of my co-workers questioned it and have a little doubt that i need to double check.

Thanks

Comment: No expiration of the certificate won't affect apps which are already on app-store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you cert. expires your already submitted apps will continue to work but you not able to update the apps until you renew your account.
And yes you already know the answer